# Can you install software and tools using a script?

Tags: 14.04, bash, scripts

I'm new to Linux but I saw someone run a script and his user profile, tools like NodeJS, VSCode, the Chrome browser etc were installed on that new machine without him doing it one by one.

How could I do something like this in ubuntu?

Comment: "*How do I make a script on a Linux-based system?*" has dozens of excellent tutorials across the internet. A more specific question is likely to result is a more satisfactory answer.

Comment: Only supported releases of Ubuntu (*standard support*) are on-topic for this site.  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is in extended support and now Ubuntu 14.04 ESM thus only supported by Canonical via Ubuntu Advantage and off-topic here.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/05/02/ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-reached-end-of-life-on-april-25-2019-esm-available/
  *You've not explicitly given your OS & release details; but you've tagged an EOL/ESM release which is off-topic*

Comment: "How could I do something like this in ubuntu?" open an editor, start typing or copy/paste commands, save it and make it executable, then execute it.  Nothing more to  it so I do not really see the reason for this question?! Being new to Linux has nothing to do with that?!  The same is possible in ANY OS. Being able to code or read and understand code is more important